# Why is only one of my Dexie queries updating in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, indexeddb, dexie

I have a `svelte` application that uses `Dexie` for data persistence. In my main component I have a child component that runs two `liveQuery`s to get the previous fixture and next fixture for a sports team. However, when advancing through time (it's a sports management simulation game) the next fixture updates reactively but the previous fixture doesn't update.

`lastFixtures` and `nextFixtures` returns an array of 10 fixtures for that round.

In the `filter` functions I'm hardcoding the ID for the team I'm using for now, this is a work in progress.

---

`FixtureSummary.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { liveQuery } from 'dexie'
  import { db } from '../../db'
  import { leagueRound } from '../../store'
  let lastFixtures = liveQuery(() =>
    db
      .fixtures
      .get($leagueRound - 1)
  )
  let nextFixtures = liveQuery(() =>
    db
      .fixtures
      .get($leagueRound)
  )
  $: lastFixture = $lastFixtures?.fixtures.filter(f => f.home.id === 15 || f.away.id === 15)[0]
  $: nextFixture = $nextFixtures?.fixtures.filter(f => f.home.id === 15 || f.away.id === 15)[0]
</script>

<div>
  <h3>Last Fixture</h3>
  {#if lastFixture}
    <p>{lastFixture.home.name} {lastFixture.homeGoals} - {lastFixture.awayGoals} {lastFixture.away.name}</p>
  {:else}
  <p>N/A</p>
  {/if}
  <h3>Next Fixture</h3>
  {#if nextFixture}
    <p>{nextFixture.home.name} vs {nextFixture.away.name}</p>
  {:else}
    <p>N/A</p>
  {/if}
</div>
```

**Question:** Why does only one of my queries update in the view of my component?

---

As a secondary question, I tried getting both the previous and next fixtures in one query like so:

```js
liveQuery(() => 
  db
    .fixtures
    .where('id')
    .anyOf([$leagueRound - 1, $leagueRound])
    .toArray()
)
```

However, that didn't seem to return anything, so any pointers on that would also be much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect the component to update when the `$leagueRound` store updates, you'd need to replace `let` with `$:` on the liveQuery rows. Also make sure to use the latest version of dexie (currently dexie@3.2.2 or dexie@4.0.0-alpha.4). Other than that, I have no explanation why the anyOf query didn't return any result or that the second query doesn't update.

If you still have a problem after changing to use `$:`, please file a new issue on [Dexie.js github site](https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js/issues/new) and supply a repro for it that is easy to execute (preferably on a site such as codesandbox or similar).

Comment: Cool, that works and makes sense, thanks. Though I'm not sure why one of the components did update when the `$leagueRound` store updated, but never mind, problem for another day!